# c# - Unable to read the circled text from an image using tessnet2 and Tesseract-OCR

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract, tessnet2

I'm trying to writte code which change text from jpg to console. I used to write: tessnet2 and Tesseract-OCR (in c#). Now everthing is work fine when I have pure text, but problem is when the text is in circle like here:

[image]

Actually console return me this:

```
118 : Text
61 : 1
219 : @
```

Sometimes it change @ to ~(depend of size of circle).
There is my code:

```
  var image = new Bitmap(@"D:\OCR\texttoread.bmp");
            tessnet2.Tesseract ocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
            ocr.Init(@"C:\tessdata", "eng", false);
            List<tessnet2.Word> result = ocr.DoOCR(image, Rectangle.Empty);
            foreach (tessnet2.Word word in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", word.Confidence, word.Text);
                }
                Console.Read();
```

Can someone tell me what I should do to read this text?

Answer (score 0):

Try Ironocr plugin and use the following. It have more accuracy I think, Hope this will help you. Please find the below code for read.

```
var Ocr = new AutoOcr();
var Result = Ocr.Read(bmpCrop);
string text = Result.Text; 
return text;
```